# MTA application with reuse Libraries

Tags: sapui5, modularization, sap-cloud-platform

We have SAP UI5 MTA application deployed in SAP CP consist of 3 apps(HTML5 modules).
All these apps right now standing independently without communicating each other.
Among these two apps controller code have similar functions thus we are having code duplication. We need to modularize this code. 
so we are planning to use Fiori libraries.
The SAP Fiori Library is not available as a project type when creating a new HTML5 module inside the WebIDE MTA project.

Refering this site below
https://github.wdf.sap.corp/fiori-cf/support/issues/377

Somebody have done it which is much complex and it is still in discussion.

Can anyone here help me out how to achieve this any better solution for my problem?

Anyone have worked on MTA projects? how can we modularize the code and reuse it in the different apps under MTA?

Comment: How did you realize this or you've put this on hold?